# Is it possible to get a subset of the results in a set for paging?

Tags: redis

I want to be able to page through the results of a set, especially if it has a few thousand items in it.

The smembers command seems to just return all the items in the set, is paging not supported?

https://redis.io/commands/smembers

Answer (score 2):

Paging in a Set isn't supported as Sets are not ordered.

There are two alternatives:

a) continue using Sets and call on [`SSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) to iterate the members. Note the `SCAN` family of commands guarantees, as this is like but not identical to paging.

b) switch to using Sorted Sets and call on [`ZRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) for full-blown paging.